# Uneditable box after ticking it

Tags: axapta, x++, dynamics-ax-2012

How can I make it after ticking the box and it turns uneditable right away?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

This question is somewhat loaded because the answer is, it depends.

Your screenshot makes it look like that control is in a **grid row**, which would imply the control is connected to a datasource. If that's the case, do you want only the checkbox to be disabled or the entire row?

You would probably put code in the datasource field's `modified` method or the datasource's `active` method.

If the checkbox is a standalone control, you would override the `clicked` method with something like:

```
public void clicked()
{
    super();

    if (this.checked())
        this.enabled(false);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe it's due to Field properties in table.
Seems like it restricts edit after creation. 
Otherwise - check code on form (or class maintaining the form). It might be on Control/Field/Datasource/Table modify method.